# Pytorch equivalent for keras Dense

Tags: keras, nlp, pytorch

I'm trying to convert some code written with keras to pytorch. I'm trying to initialize multiple layers in the init function. The code to be converted is :

```
self.layers_li = []
for i in range(num_layers):
   self.layers_li.append(layers.Dense(input_dim, activation='relu'))
```

I think using pytorch.nn.Linear would do, but nn.Linear doesn't specify activation function as a parameter. How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the most basic example of how you can achieve what you want:

```py
import torch
from torch import nn

m = nn.Linear(20, 30)
n = nn.ReLU()

input = torch.randn(128, 20)
output = m(input)
output_activated = n(output)
```

So, you can actually have nonlinearity followed by linearity.